# Extracting pack size from a product description

Tags: python-2.7

I have a column `product_desc` in product table that tells about brand, size of the product e.g `'COKE BOTTLE 2L'` , `'SUNFEAST 50GM'`, `'BANANA 12PC'`. How to extract this information? I m working in python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a sql select query to your database, I assume your table name is `product`, so you need something like this

```
result = cursor.execute("SELECT product_desc FROM product").fetchall()
```

Comment: I need to extract pack size info like '2L' , '50gm' etc.. from product_desc